# Ubuntu Touch - adding time & date stamp to photos

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there a setting or an app that I can use to add a time and date stamp to the photos that I take using my Touch phone? This is very useful to have when trying to sort out all the photos on my hard drive.

Comment: On my phone the timestamp is already in the file name. Can't you use that? If not, please explain why.

Comment: Oh yes I have that and always use that. Having the stamp on the photo too would be very nice.

Comment: I have been looking around, but at the moment there does not seem to be any option to adding a date and time stamp to your pictures. Does anyone know if there are any plans to address this soon?

Comment: I have raised this in Launchpad under https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/archipel-agent-iphone-notification/+bug/1598991

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is to watermark your photos with the date/time they were taken then check out http://jambula.sourceforge.net/ to batch insert shooting date/time/comment on jpeg images in different formats and languages. A special feature is that the date stamp is lossless. It is supported on Linux as well.

Comment: I have asked a question in the camera app section of Launchpad to see if there are any plans to allow this functionality to be added.

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/camera-app/+question/296401

Comment: I have now raised this as a bug under Bug #1603416

Comment: Some good news. The big that I raised for this has today been set to confirmed as multiple users are affected. Hopefully this will start making some progress now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may still be interested in this topic, in has been resolved in the UBPorts release of the software. Basic but it looks good and does what is needed.