# Timestamp photos in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, camera

When I take photos on my phone or tablet, I like to timestamp them in the bottom corner, so I can sort them out easier later. How can I do this in Ubuntu Touch when using my phone or tablet? I know you can see then they were taken at file level, but that is not what I am looking for. On my andriod phone there is a app I have that adds the stamp to all the pictures that I take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question that I asked a bit ago, which is along the lines of yours [Timestamp question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788869/ubuntu-touch-adding-time-date-stamp-to-photos)

I raised this in launchpad under [Bug #1603416](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/camera-app/+bug/1603416). Add comments to this if it is what you want and also add the fact that it affects you. That way we may be able to get this moving and get a solution sooner rather than later. I will be raising a bug for this and when I have the number I will add it here.

Comment: I will keep an eye on this one and add comments in Launchpad. Hopefully, we will get a fix for it soon.